# missing dependency POM reported in Windows 7 but not in Windows 10

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a Maven project which has a dependency on an Oracle JDBC library i.e. the entry in the project pom.xml is

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have a copy of this project on 2 different machines; one running Windows 7 and one running Windows 10 (the version of Maven is the same; 3.6.3 and the required dependency exists in the default local repository; .m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar)

When I run `mvn clean package` on the Windows 10 machine, no errors are returned and the relevant target files are created. However, when I run `mvn clean package` on the Windows 7 machine, an error occurs complaining about a missing dependency POM file; ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom.

I can work around this problem by manually creating this file on the Windows 7 machine, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
</project>
```

I don't understand why I need to do this!!????

Answer (score 1):

ojbdb7 is not part of official Maven repositories.

You need to add it manually to your company repository or to your local repository.

I assume that one of your local repositories has it and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Meier is right. There is nothing related to different OS version. The environment on its working because you already have that jar on your local repo or within the classpath of your project. I had also faced the same issue sometime back with same ojdbc7 jar. So to get rid of that we copied the jar in our libs folder of the project so that the jar was available in project classpath.

Comment: Usually you put it into your company Nexus/Artifactory.

Comment: Thats right Meier.  Later we had moved it to our nexus P2 repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest Oracle JDBC driver which is 21.1.0.0.
If you have JDK8, then you can use ojdbc8.jar from [12.2.0.1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/)

```
<groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>12.2.0.1</version>
```